# Add custom border to certain cells in a matplotlib / seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Right now I`m using Seaborn's clustermap to generate some clustered heatmaps - so far so good.

For a certain use case, I need to draw colored borders around specific cells. Is there a way to do that? Or with pcolormesh in matplotlib, or any other way?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can do this by overplotting a [Rectangle patch](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) on the cell that you would want to highlight. Using the example plot  from the [seaborn docs](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html)

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set()
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
g = sns.clustermap(flights)
```

We can highlight a cell by doing

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
ax = g.ax_heatmap

ax.add_patch(Rectangle((3, 4), 1, 1, fill=False, edgecolor='blue', lw=3))
plt.show()
```

This will produce the plot with a highlighted cell like so:

[image]

Note the the indexing of the cells is 0 based with the origin at the bottom left.

Comment: That is just plain wonderful, thanks a lot! I also have a more complex case - what if multiple highlighted cells that touch each other, and I want to draw borders around them, but get rid of internal borders within a block of highlighted cells? Maybe I should open a new question for that?

Comment: Answering to myself, I think I can do it with a Polygon patch, thanks Simon!

Comment: How do you add a patch if your plot of cells isn't in a variable? How do you put a normal matplotlib cell matrix into a variable to achieve this method?