# SeaBorn Heatmap: add padding for Rectangle overlay

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In user **@SimonGibbons**' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31291200/5623899) to [Add custom border to certain cells in a matplotlib / seaborn plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290778/add-custom-border-to-certain-cells-in-a-matplotlib-seaborn-plot)

a cell is highlighted via:

```
ax = g.ax_heatmap

ax.add_patch(Rectangle((3, 4), 1, 1, fill=False, edgecolor='blue', lw=3))
```

notably, the line width (`lw`), here is set to 3. When highlighting a cell at the edge of the plot, I have found that the line gets cut off as half of the line width is inside the plot and half outside.

How can I add lw / 2 padding to the frame of the heat map using seaborn to see the entire highlighted area?

Comment: I don't think you would want to add "padding to the frame"; rather you would exclude the rectangle from being clipped by the axes. `clip_on=False`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for both finding the similar question and the answer.